# 9 in 4 card reader/writer doesn't read SD cards on Debian 11 Bullseye

Tags: debian, sd-card

Since my new Acer Aspire Vero laptop doesn't have an SD card slot I dug up my old Dane-Elec 9 in 4 Reader/Writer. However this seems unable to access the photos on my SD cards. Even though it works fine with Compact Flash cards from a different camera.

I'm running Debian 11 Bullseye on the laptop.

After attaching the reader to the laptop `dmesg` gives this:

```
[  282.254111] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  282.418833] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0a48, idProduct=3244, bcdDevice= 1.28
[  282.418838] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  282.418841] usb 1-5: Product: DANE-ELEC COMBO 9IN4
[  282.418843] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Dane-Elec
[  282.418845] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 01812
[  282.486012] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  282.486076] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[  282.486118] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  282.487751] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  283.496105] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  283.497340] scsi 2:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  283.498514] scsi 2:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  283.499699] scsi 2:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  283.507069] scsi 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  283.507087] scsi 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  283.507101] scsi 2:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  283.507115] scsi 2:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  283.552980] sd 2:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  283.557037] sd 2:0:0:3: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  283.570625] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  283.573271] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Which initially looks kind of okay to me. Then when I insert an SD card I get:

```
[  398.577100] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[  399.590108] ..
[  431.250334] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  431.405307] ready
```

Which still looks good, until the "reset" line starts repeating itself many many times:

```
[  461.970460] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  492.690490] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  523.410480] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  554.130487] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  584.850283] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  615.570507] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  646.290252] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  677.010264] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  707.730421] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  738.454416] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  769.170202] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  799.890229] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  800.043944] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdd] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  800.043947] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdd] Sense not available.
[  830.614347] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  861.330361] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
...
```

I've tried this multiple times with different cards that work fine on my camera. When I try the same with a Compact Flash card `dmesg` gives this:

```
[ 1047.640247] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[ 1048.647643] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1048.648777] scsi 2:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1048.649857] scsi 2:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1048.650969] scsi 2:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0128 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1048.651444] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 1048.651758] sd 2:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1048.652013] scsi 2:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1048.652280] sd 2:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1048.691368] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1048.706753] sd 2:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1048.712099] sd 2:0:0:3: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1048.725542] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1077.007337] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 4001760 512-byte logical blocks: (2.05 GB/1.91 GiB)
[ 1077.012676]  sda: sda1
```

...and the contents of the card show up in my file manager like they're supposed to. I can also safely remove the card.

Can it be something to do with this `xhci_hcd`? I tried searching drivers for Dane-Elec card readers but couldn't find any.

Any suggestions would be welcome: thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with the USB connection between your laptop and the Dane-Elec 9 in 4 Reader/Writer. The repeated "reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd" messages in the dmesg output indicate that the USB controller is resetting the connection with the reader multiple times, which could be causing problems with the SD card access.

There are a few things you can try to fix this issue:

Try using a different USB cable to connect the reader to the laptop.
Try connecting the reader to a different USB port on the laptop.
Try connecting the reader to a different computer to see if the issue is specific to your laptop.
Try updating the USB controller driver on your laptop.
Make sure the power supply of the laptop is stable, If it's not and your laptop is running on battery, try to plug it in.
Try removing and reinserting the SD card in the reader multiple times.
If none of these steps work, it's possible that the issue is with the reader itself, and you may need to consider getting a replacement.

You should also make sure that you are running the latest version of your system firmware and the latest Linux kernel.
It is also a good idea to check if there is any related kernel message to this issue by checking the log file in /var/log/messages or using dmesg | grep -i error or dmesg | grep -i fail to see if there is any error/failure messages related to this.

Comment: Tried your suggestions: Combo still doesn't read SD cards but you put me on the right track. Let me break it down: 1._different USB cable_: not an option as USB thingy directly connected to device; 2._different USB port_: same result; 3._different computer_: same result on Toshiba laptop with Debian 9; 4._power supply_: same result with power chord attached; 5._removing and reinserting_: same result; (6. also tried on win11 with similar result: device recognized but no directories); 7._latest version_: according to apt-get and synaptic everything is up to date (more in next comment)

Comment: 8. _error/failure messages_ : "... [ 2724.339533] sd 2:0:0:2: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK" appears after disconnecting the device. It seems the device will only work with Compact Flash cards. However the first suggestion reminded me of the fact that the camera probably came with its own USB cable. I'd completely forgotten about that because my old laptop had this very convenient SD card slot. Turns out attaching the camera directly to my laptop works like a charm.